# Scanning over a merge of differently typed signals

Tags: reactive-cocoa

Suppose I have a signal of arrays `arraySignal`, and a signal of objects `addedObjectsSignal`.

I would like to define a third signal, `modifiedArraySignal`, that takes the latest array from `arraySignal` and adds to it the objects from `addedObjectsSignal` sent *since* the latest array from `arraySignal`.

Here's one way to do it:

```
    RACSignal *modifiedArraySignal =
    [[RACSignal
     merge:@[arraySignal, addedObjectsSignal]]
     scanWithStart:@[]
     reduce:^(id running, id next) {
         if ([next isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]])
             return next;
         else
             return [running arrayByAddingObject:next];
     }];
```

Is there another approach that doesn't use `-[NSObject isKindOfClass:]`?

Comment: I should point out that this approach breaks on arrays of arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Originally a comment, but, code formatting.*

When a new array is sent, do you want updates to previous arrays to stop? In other words, if, after array B is sent, do you want both scans on array A and array B to operate simultaneously, or not? If you want updates to prior arrays to stop, use `-map:`/`-switchToLatest` instead of `-flattenMap:`:

```
RACSignal *modifiedArraySignal = [[arraySignal
    map:^(NSArray *array) {
        return [[addedObjectsSignal
            scanWithStart:array reduce:^(NSArray *running, id next) {
                return [running arrayByAddingObject:next];
            }]
            startWith:array];
    }]
    switchToLatest];
```

Comment: Nice. I just edited my own answer to give it the property of stopping updates on prior arrays, but your solution is more elegant.

Comment: Thanks. Your `-takeUntil:` approach should behave identically.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a solution that I like better than the one I gave in my question, and which I think is equivalent:

```
RACSignal * modifiedArraySignal =
[arraySignal flattenMap:^(NSArray *array) {
    return [[[addedObjectsSignal
            takeUntil:[arraySignal skip:1]]
            scanWithStart:array
            reduce:^(NSArray *running, id next) {
                return [running arrayByAddingObject:next];
            }]
            startWith:array];
}];
```